# xamarin - Resource.designer.cs special character issue

Tags: java, xamarin, character, r.java-file, remove-if

The auto_generated code is below:

```
public partial class Id
{
    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050002  [issue is here]
    public const int HotDog/NametextView = 2131034114;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050001
    public const int HotDogImageView = 2131034113;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050008
    public const int MyButton = 2131034120;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050006
    public const int amountEditText = 2131034118;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050005
    public const int cancelButton = 2131034117;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050000
    public const int mainScrollView = 2131034112;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050007
    public const int orderButton = 2131034119;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050004
    public const int pricetextView = 2131034116;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7f050003
    public const int shortDescriptiontextView = 2131034115;

    static Id()
    {
        global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
    }

    public const int HotDog/NametextView = 2131034114;
```

A slash is generated automatically.

If I remove that manually will that have any side effects?

It gives an error in "R.java"

```
 public static final class id {
        public static final int HotDog/NametextView=0x7f050002;
        public static final int HotDogImageView=0x7f050001;
        public static final int MyButton=0x7f050008;
        public static final int amountEditText=0x7f050006;
        public static final int cancelButton=0x7f050005;
        public static final int mainScrollView=0x7f050000;
```

Can I remove both "/" and proceed? will it give any issues?

Comment: Can you post the respective class's namespace of the item generating the `/`? i.e. `HotDog/NametextView`. You will want to fix this on the class end so the `Resource.designer.cs` can properly generate. Modifying it in the `Resource.designer.cs` file is a one time thing and will regenerate next compile. It is advised to not do that.

Comment: my axml had issues and / existed there, which inturn came in these files

Comment: Sorry for trouble and thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: the issue is solved..but i am facing another issue which i have posted on another post...As described the issue was  my axml had issues and / existed there, which inturn came in these files